# php - Inserting a MySQL table column into a PHP document

Tags: php, mysql

I'm new to PHP and have been working on a variation of a system I am using. This system is comprised of PHP, HTML and CSS (duh). It's a user registration and management system.

At current, if I want to insert the current user's email address, all I have to do is insert `<?= $fgmembersite->UserEmail(); ?>` and it will display the current user's email address.

I've added a custom field to my database table, and want to be able to reference it on the page, like the above code does.

Here is a screenshot of my MySQL table:
[image]

And here is a pastebin of my PHP:
**[Pastebin](http://pastebin.com/0k5Q2qUq)**

I apologize if i'm not making much sense, I am new to PHP and are really trying my hardest to make this question as easy as possible for any possible helpers. Thankyou in advance.

Comment: So you're wanting to display information from a row specific to a user?

Comment: Yes, and if possible the "domain" field too.. It doesn't display on the page no matter what I try :/

Comment: Did you attempt my answer?

Comment: Yes, it doesn't seem to work for me

Comment: I've been trying desperately to find anything online that can help me but I can't seem to come up with anything.. I've figured out the username thing but I can't get the domain field to show up for me.. I've even resorted to testing and trying things for myself. Here's a link to the latest version of my php: http://pastebin.com/1JZ9Huhi Thank you so much for helping me, I'm trying so hard to get this working and I feel like i'm out of options.

Comment: I updated the answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After looking through your code I found your mistake. The mistake is in

```
function CheckLoginInDB($username,$password)
```

In `$qry` you selected columns name and email but not domain.

You should replace `$qry` with the following:

```
$qry = "SELECT name, email, domain FROM $this->tablename WHERE username='$username' AND password='$pwdmd5' AND confirmcode='y'";
```

Comment: Thank you so much! It worked! I completely overlooked the `$qry` variable